# Can someone help me give a function to %>%

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I am trying to get %>% to resemble a function like this

```
phase<-csvdata%>%
    filter(csvdata$phase=="test")
```

or like this

```
mergedrows1<-phase%>%
    group_by(phase$subject,phase$phase)
```

where I can group specific variables together from a data frame.

Comment: Don't use `data$column` inside `dplyr` functions - it expects unquoted column names. `csvdata %>% filter(phase == "test")`. etc. Other than that, I have no idea what your question is - you show examples gives two functions to `%>%`, `filter` in the first example, `group_by` in the second. What are you trying to do that you're not able to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of the `%>%` pipe is that the first argument (typically reserved to be for the name of the data frame you are manipulating in most pipe-friendly functions) is moved ahead of the pipe. In other words, `f(x, y)` is equivalent to `x %>% f(y)`. In plain English, think of it as "take this data and then apply this function".

The problem with your code is that you are calling a variable within a data frame twice, which leaves the `dplyr` functions like `filter()` and `group_by()` confused. You are calling the data frame once when you say `csvdata %>%` and again when you say `csvdata$phase`. You don't need to use `dataframe$variable` in a tidyverse setting. Indeed that is what the pipe is seeking you to avoid doing.

Instead you only need to do something like:

```
phase <- csvdata %>%
  filter(phase == "test")
```

Or

```
mergedrows1 <- phase %>%
  group_by(subject, phase)
```

Also, it's a bad idea to give the same name to a data frame and a variable within the data frame. R will not get confused, but you or a reader of the code will be.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I figured it out, and those comments are noted thank you once more!